# SCOPE for a table of REFs

Tags: sql, oracle, object-type, object-relational-model

I am designing an object-relational model with Oracle (18.4.0) and I would like to add a `SCOPE` constraint to a table type column of an object table. Is it possible? Here a simplified model:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_cycler AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE cycler OF t_cycler (
    name PRIMARY KEY
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_cycler_list IS TABLE OF REF t_cycler;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_team AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2(50),
    cyclers t_cycler_list
);

CREATE TABLE team OF t_team (
    name PRIMARY KEY
)
NESTED TABLE cyclers STORE AS cyclers_tab;
```

I need that `team.cyclers` only contains `REF`s to objects in `cycler`. I look into the documentation but unfortunately it does not say a lot about `SCOPE` constraint, like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/key-features-object-relational-model.html#GUID-5D5A3A90-914E-49D6-B561-958FB2871EC4):

> You can constrain a column type, **collection element**, or object type
> attribute to reference a specified object table. Use the SQL
> constraint subclause SCOPE IS when you declare the REF.

But the only example it provides is about a simple column type. I tried specifying `SCOPE IS cycler` in several ways inside the creation of the `team` table but with no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add the scope to the `COLUMN_VALUE` pseudo-column of the nested table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE cyclers_tab ADD SCOPE FOR ( COLUMN_VALUE ) IS cycler;
```

If you then do:

```sql
INSERT INTO cycler ( name ) VALUES ( 'c1.1' );
INSERT INTO cycler ( name ) VALUES ( 'c1.2' );

INSERT INTO team (
  name,
  cyclers
) VALUES (
  'team1',
  t_cycler_list(
    ( SELECT REF(c) FROM cycler c WHERE name = 'c1.1' ),
    ( SELECT REF(c) FROM cycler c WHERE name = 'c1.2' )
  )
);
```

Then you can insert the row. But, if you have another table of the same object type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cycler2 OF t_cycler (
    name PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO cycler2 ( name ) VALUES ( 'c2.1' );
```

And try to do:

```sql
INSERT INTO team (
  name,
  cyclers
) VALUES (
  'team2',
  t_cycler_list(
    ( SELECT REF(c) FROM cycler2 c WHERE name = 'c2.1' )
  )
);
```

Then you get the error:

> ```
> ORA-22889: REF value does not point to scoped table
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=257b22324fa7e2f95e2ee89cbb621373)*

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a question: I knew the `COLUMN_VALUE` pseudo-column but I had no idea how to use it in this case. Did you read that `ALTER TABLE...` statement somewhere (in this case, can you tell me where please?) or you are just very clever? :)

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara No, I couldn't find it documented anywhere. There were two options that I could think of. Either (1) it can't be done; or (2) it needed to be applied to some column of the nested table and the only columns to apply it to were are pseudo-columns. I just started trying each pseudo-column I could think of until I found one that worked.