# How to create a nested table of refs in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, ref, object-oriented-database, nested-table

Consider the following problem:

> There's the **Transaction** type and the **Service** type. Each transaction covers one or more services at a time. However, two different transactions may cover same services.

Now, it's pretty easy to consolidate this using relational database design. You'd have a table for transactions `transaction id, and then some data fields`, a table for services `service id, some data fields` and a third table that links transaction id's to service id's. This way, the service data is not duplicated and if you ever needed to, say, retrieve all services implicated in a transaction, you just do two joins `transactions join third_table join service`.

As far as I understand, `ref` simply stores the id of the record (object) it's pointing to and implicitly does a join upon `deref()`. So, say, if any of the transactions had to cover just one of the services, I could use a `ref` to the service object instead of the service id + an explicit join.

A `nested table`, as far as I understand, is just a private table that links the id of one object to a whole another object and that is shared among all objects of the type that declared the nested table. This concept also uses joins under the hood, if I'm not being horribly wrong. So if the services were unique among all transactions, I could in principle just use a `nested table of services` inside the transaction.

However, the problem is that there could be more than one service for every transaction **and** they could repeat. So the object-oriented solution, in my mind, is a `nested table of ref to service` inside of the transaction. However, I'm not able to find any clues on the Internet for the syntax for this idea and whether it is at all possible to do this.

Here's Oracle SQL sort of pseudocode (it doesn't work) of what I'm aiming for:

```sql
create type Service_Type as object(
    id           number(5),
    -- some other data --
    cost         number(4),
    name         varchar2(32),
    description  varchar2(32)
    ---------------------
);
/
create table Service_Table of Service_Type (id primary key);
/
create type Service_Reference_Type as ref Service_Type scope is Service_Table;
/
create type Service_Reference_Table_Type as table of Service_Reference_Type;
/

create type Transaction_Type as object(
    id           number(5),
    services     Service_Reference_Table_Type,
    -- some other data --
    name         varchar2(32),
    description  varchar2(32)
    ---------------------
);
nested table services store as Transaction_Service_Nested_Reference_Table;
/
```

As a sidenote: I know Object Oriented DBMS is garbage and I'm not planning on using it in any real project. This is for a university assignment (I wonder why they teach this stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're too far off, but you don't need `Service_Reference_Type`, you can create a table of refs in one step:

```
create type Service_Type as object(
    id           number(5),
    -- some other data --
    cost         number(4),
    name         varchar2(32),
    description  varchar2(32)
    ---------------------
);
/

create table Service_Table of Service_Type (id primary key);

create type Service_Reference_Table_Type as table of ref Service_Type;
/

create type Transaction_Type as object(
    id           number(5),
    services     Service_Reference_Table_Type,
    -- some other data --
    name         varchar2(32),
    description  varchar2(32)
    ---------------------
)
/

create table Transaction_Table of Transaction_Type
nested table services store as Transaction_Service_Nested_Reference_Table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4399925391ef8388da12158dcd02f00) including inserting and querying the data.

> Is there a way one could scope the refs too?

As in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162253/scope-for-a-table-of-refs/65162505#65162505) @MTO linked to:

```
alter table Transaction_Service_Nested_Reference_Table
add scope for (column_value) is Service_Table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e65fa5660481ec35a33e850c9fe6675)

Comment: Thanks, that really does work. Is there a way one could scope the refs too?

Comment: @AntonCurmanschii See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162253/scope-for-a-table-of-refs/65162505#65162505) for applying scope to a nested table.